# Store temporarily data on browser

Tags: javascript

Can we temporarily store data on browser ?
For an example , i have page A and page B

On page A(a.html) , i would want to temporarily store text "Helloworld" on button click

```
function a(){
  return "helloWorld"
}

function changePage(){
  a()
  window.location(b.html)
}
```

On page B(B.html), i would want then to capture "Helloworld" on page A and print it on page b.

```
console.log(a())
```

I read on postMessage but based on my understanding , this only works on 2 page thats loaded on a single page on cross-domain workaround.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the browser’s local-storage capabilities: **localStorage**. It helps to store data on the browser as **strings**.

To store data:

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'helloWorld');
```

To get the saved data:

```
localStorage.getItem('foo');// return 'helloWorld'
```

Comment: Thanks @ahmad , i have checked and it solve the issue but i was wondering , for best practice purposes, will this approach cause any cross-domain origin ?

Comment: I can not see any cause to have cross-domain problems since the localStorage works on the client's side (the browser) and the check of the cross-domain is done on the server's side.

Comment: cross-domain problems are related to whether the server will permit or not the actual request, which is not related to your case.

Answer (score 1):

I think `sessionStorage` fits your purpose. But mind that the data is removed when the user closes the browser - if you don't want that, simply replace `sessionStorage` with `localStorage`. But as long as you don't need the data to be persistent across restarts you should rather use `sessionStorage` to not fill up the users disk:

#### a.html

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // this is executed when the site is loaded
  inputElement = document.getElementById("dataInput");
  inputElement.addEventListener("input", function() { // and this whenever the user changes the contents of dataInput
    window.sessionStorage.setItem("dataInput", inputElement.value());
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="dataInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter your data">
```

#### b.html

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  outputElement = document.getElementById("dataOutput");
  outputElement.setText(window.sessionStorage.getItem("dataInput"));
});
```

```html
<p id="dataOutput">The data should appear here</p>
```

Comment: I also thought of session storage first, but this statement on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) made we wonder whether it would actually work (I haven't tested it): *"Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work."* I read that as that every tab gets its own session storage but maybe I'm misinterpreting this.

Comment: @FelixKling oh, then maybe you'd rather transform the browser into an oven and [bake some cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).